# How to set English as a default language in Debian?

Tags: debian, locale

How can I set English as a default language in Debian ?
I've installed Debian in a different language.

```
$ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US  
update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANGUAGE=en_US LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 14):

Using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` should work.

Comment: By that, English has become a default language.

Comment: thnks, that worked! for information, the answer in https://serverfault.com/questions/301896/how-to-fix-locale-settings-in-debian-squeeze is similar + gives more details if needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit file:**

```
# vim /etc/default/locale
```

**and write the following uncommented line**:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

**and then comment the current uncommented lines and uncomment the line with** `en_US.UTF-8` (in the same file):

```
# en_US.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
# en_ZA ISO-8859-1
```

**Save file and run**:

```
# locale-gen
```

**and restart the terminal**.

For me, these steps work. I hope it helps you too.

Comment: I think the first and second file path are the same

Comment: Yes, you're right @MailoSvětel! I fixed it just now. Thank you!

Comment: I get `Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8...Killed` on Debian 11 trying to run locale-gen!

Answer (score 1):

Can you start with the output of `env | grep LANG`? Make sure those all point to the proper lang/country, then do the dpkg command as mentioned by @vlp

Answer (score 0):

Check the language environment variable: `LC_LANG`.

An easier way is to set the `LC_ALL` or `LC_*` variable to the value `en_GB.UTF-8`.